# How to put <a> link tag in the middle of a page

Tags: html, css

i wanna making a link in the middle of the page, this is what i have done: (Im sorry im new)

```css
.list2 {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<li class="list2"><a href="#">Discord</a></li><br>              
<li class="list2"><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need in your CSS is:

```
.list2 
    {
     text-align: center !important;
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
    }
```

The `!important` tag is to override any existing css that could be preventing this.

For instance, Bootstrap will override a lot of custom CSS so if text-align: center isn't working the `!important` will fix that.

and your html should be:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list2"><a href="#">Discord</a></li>
    <li class="list2"><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
</ul>
```

You could also wrap a div around your links and just apply the list2 class to that div and it should take care of aligning both links center. For instance:

```
<ul>
    <div class="list2">
        <li><a href="www.discord.com">Discord</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

It's always good practice not to write the same peice of code twice if you don't have to. Also, don't forget that `<ul>` tags.

Comment: The div should be set to width 100% if the objects are still left-anchored.

Comment: I didn't account for that but good catch. Just edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

You need add this styles for ul parent block:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100vh;` under a new `.container` in your stylesheet and put your second link in the same div like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <li class="list2">
    <a>link1</a>
    <a>link2</a>
  </li>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }
</style>
```

You can also remove `align-content` as you do not need it. If you need anymore help feel free to reply or even make a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Apply this css it will move to center

```
 .list2 {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```